# Spring beans autowiring issue in composer layer for ZKoss after upgrade

Tags: spring, zk

My application was working perfectly fine on ZKoss 5.x before upgrade we recently upgraded to Zkoss 6.5.2. 
In the composer layer we have autowired the service Spring beans, before upgraded they were totally fine but after the ZK upgrade to latest version 6.5.2 all service beans are null ( not auto wired) and  all are throwing Null Pointer Exception. I am not sure if I am missing something.
I am stuck on this .
Can any one please help or give some ideas how to go about it?

Is there any dependencies on new Spring version ? Or any JDK version?
I am using JDK 7 minor version 21 on windows box with Spring 3.0.

Zul file code :

```
<?variable-resolver class="org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver"?>
<?init class="org.zkoss.zkplus.databind.AnnotateDataBinderInit" arg0="./myWin"?>
```

```
<groupbox width="1310px">
    <caption label="More"/>
    <a id="screenLink">Local transfers screen</a>
</groupbox>

<timer id="timer" delay="3000" repeats="true"/>
```

Composer class:

```
public class ZYZComposer extends GenericForwardComposer {
    private MyService transferService;
    private Window myWin;
    private A screenLink;

    public ZYZComposer() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {
        super.doAfterCompose(comp);
        if (transferService.isEnabled()) {
            screenLink.setHref(transferService.getScreenUrl());
        } else {
            myWin.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    public void onTimer$timer() {
        if (transferService.isEnabled())  { // Some logic  }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Please post the code (an example), that do not work.

Comment: Agreed, please post some example code of how you are trying to autowire things in the composer. Without this we cannot possibly help.

Comment: guys, I have updated the question with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced this problem before and used quick hack: `SpringUtil.getBean("myBean");`

I also found some other workaround to this which I've not tested, may be you can test it:

```
public class SearchController extends SelectorComposer {

 public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {

    super.doAfterCompose(comp);
    Selectors.wireVariables(getPage(), this, _resolvers);

}
```

}

have a look at this [zk bug](http://tracker.zkoss.org/browse/ZK-1542) also.

Comment: check this as well http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Essentials/Chapter%209:%20Spring%20Integration

Answer (score 0):

Update [zkjsp](http://www.zkoss.org/download/zkjsp).

Take a look at this [bug](http://tracker.zkoss.org/browse/ZKJSP-11)

Comment: Hi Nabil, thanks. I updated the zkjsp but we continue go get NPE.

Comment: Does the workaround solve the problem? Maybe the bug is not fixed.